# android google map navgation UI integration.

Tags: android, google-maps, uinavigationcontroller

> In my application i wants to integrate the Google map and have to send the current location to server. i have integrated Google map and everything is working fine.
>
> my another requirement is i wants to put a navigation UI Inside my application like traveling from location to TO location, same like Navigation UI in android .

[image: like same on image]

> How can i achieve this , is there any API or any library file. please suggest me some useful link

Comment: [Google Maps Android API v2 | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would need locations API or Places API based on the need of your app. In order to set up a fully loaded map app you should use some other API references too. This [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker) will help you pick suitable APIs for your app.

Also, go [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html) to check for UI elements references.

Hope these documentation helped.